# Error using msnodesql when trying to connect to a SQL server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, webpack, next.js

I'm working on connecting to a SQL server database, it has to be using Windows Authentication due to project constraints, so according to what I've found on the internet, msnodesql is my only option. The project is using next.js. If there is a different option I'm willing to look into something else.

My issue is that I've been getting this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

The solution written there is to add the loader, I don't know if I did it correctly, but this is the next.config.js I've made:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: "node-loader",
    });
    config.resolve = {
        ...config.resolve,
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
            path: false,
            os: false,
            timers: false,
            stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        },
        preferRelative: true,
    }
    config.experiments = {
        ...config.experiments,
        topLevelAwait: true,
    }
    return config;
    },
  };
```

Once this loader is added, I get a runtime exception:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: node-loader:
TypeError: process.dlopen is not a function
```

The error in the inspect console is:

```
Uncaught Error: node-loader:
TypeError: process.dlopen is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build/Release/sqlserverv8.node:8:9)
    at ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/build/Release/sqlserverv8.node (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:968:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/connection.js:10:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/connection.js:652:3)
    at ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/connection.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:264:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/sql.js:23:13)
    at ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/sql.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:402:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mssql/lib/msnodesqlv8/connection-pool.js:3:19)
    at ./node_modules/mssql/lib/msnodesqlv8/connection-pool.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:599:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mssql/lib/msnodesqlv8/index.js:4:24)
    at ./node_modules/mssql/lib/msnodesqlv8/index.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:610:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mssql/msnodesqlv8.js:1:18)
    at ./node_modules/mssql/msnodesqlv8.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:685:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/API/connection.js:44:11)
    at ./src/API/connection.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:728:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/quiz-portal.js:10:76)
    at __webpack_require__.a (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:124:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/quiz-portal.js:1:21)
    at ./src/pages/quiz-portal.js (quiz-portal.js?ts=1655217855254:948:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:700:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1655217855254:369:21)
    at eval (next-client-pages-loader.js?page=%2Fquiz-portal&absolutePagePath=D%3A%5CDFM%5Cchoosingwisely%5Cchoosing-wisely%5Csrc%5Cpages%5Cquiz-portal.js!:5:16)
    at eval (route-loader.js:221:24)
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? I have tried re-installing my node_modules folder, the only suggestion I have found elsewhere. I only need one of these errors solved as far as I know. I am also open to different libraries to connect to the database, but it needs to be a SQL server using Windows Authentication

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you show us the code that generated the original error you were getting? What specific library were you trying to use?

Comment: @juliomalves, the code that generates the original error is simply trying to create the connection, and has worked before, and I haven't changed it. The library is msnodesql, perhaps I am using the term library incorrectly .

Comment: Can you share the code for the `/src/pages/quiz-portal.js` and `/src/API/connection.js` files?